# How to change highlighted color of buttons in UIActionSheet - iPad

Tags: ipad, uibutton, uiactionsheet, uicolor

I would change the highlighted color of buttons in UIActionSheet in iPad app, because I need to change the default blue in an another color... I only found solution that uses undocumented function, and maybe this is the only way to do this ! But I would avoid to use a solution that could prevent me to go on the App Store...

Any ideas or github project to link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
   - (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {

    //Gets an array af all of the subviews of our actionSheet
    NSArray *subviews = [actionSheet subviews];

    for (UIView *v in subviews) {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *b = (UIButton*)v;
            [b setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backActionSheetHighlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [b setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backActionSheet.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }   
}
```

the result is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

follow the link, you will find how to add subview in action sheet http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=301851. Then in button you can try this:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImageByColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted ];
```

Comment: How can I access to the buttons in the UIActionSheet ?

Comment: Even if the method you had suggest, doesn't exist, I vote your answer because you link me an useful source.

Comment: hahaha....glad to hear that your problem is solved. In my answer myButton was a obj of UIButton class, I wanted to give you a hint about UIControlStateHighlighted property and the example was about initializing subView in actionSheet and you got that point.... :-)